# How to make sure future rows of a DataFrame are not accessed relative to each row

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, vectorization

I have a DataFrame with `pd.DatetimeIndex` index and a single numerical column, `price` (bitcoin data).

```
                       price
timestamp   
2022-01-01 00:00:00 46250.00
2022-01-01 00:01:00 46312.76
2022-01-01 00:02:00 46368.73
2022-01-01 00:03:00 46331.08
2022-01-01 00:04:00 46321.34
... ...
2023-02-28 23:55:00 23116.25
2023-02-28 23:56:00 23121.22
2023-02-28 23:57:00 23121.42
2023-02-28 23:58:00 23122.22
2023-02-28 23:59:00 23141.57
```

I am building a platform where users can write their **vectorized** functions to predict future price of bitcoin. An example of such function would be:

```py
def future_price_will_be_higher(df):
    return df.shift(1) < df
```

I want to make sure predictions cannot use future data. E.g., if user is predicting a price for row with datetime `2022-06-01 00:00`, he should not be able to access rows after that date. E.g, user should be able to write `df.shift(-1)` because shifting by `-1` shifts into the future.

Mathematically speaking, if user is computing a value for `df[i]`, he should not be able to access rows `df[j]`, where `j > i`.

Is there a way of analyzing the code or modifying the `df` to make sure vectorized pandas functions  cannot access future rows relative to each row in the DataFrame?

I was thinking about subclassing `pd.DataFrame` and overriding `.shift(period)` to make sure it cannot accept negative `period` but is it enough to override only `.shift` or are there any other functions I need to override?

And the problem with overriding is that as soon as any operation is done on the overriden `df`, the type is reset back to `pd.DataFrame`:

```py
class OverridenDataFrame(pd.DataFrame):
    def shift(self, periods: int = ..., freq=..., axis=..., fill_value=...) -> pd.DataFrame:
        assert periods > 0, periods
        return super().shift(periods, freq, axis, fill_value)

df = OverridenDataFrame(df)
print(type(df))  # OverridenDataFrame
df = df[:]  # slicing or any other method returns pd.DataFrame
print(type(df))  # pd.DataFrame
```

Comment: If a user can execute a Python expression freely, there is no way to handle this safely in Python, only on process level secured by the OS. Many years ago there was a try to create a restricted environment in Python ("rexec", "bastion") but it failed.

Comment: Security is not my concern. My concern is that if user is computing a value for df[i], he should not be able to access rows df[j], where j > i.

Comment: Preventing access to some data is a security concern. The only way I see is to run the user code in a separate isolated process which can only access the allowed parts of the df. This can be done e. g. by creating a shortened copy of the dataframe as a file or by a pipe to a separate (server) process which provides the shortened dataframe (but doesn't execute user code).